# How to keep fragment view state?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have doubt in fragment system.

I have two fragments like **A and B**

If i move **A** to **B**,

```
Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.B)
```

Now **A** fragment onDestroyView is called i know it's normal.
After in **B** Fragment i called PopBackStack

```
Navigation.findNavController(v).popBackStack()
```

now **A** fragment onViewCreated is called i also know it's normal.
Now **A** fragment all ui is initial state.

**My question is how to keep A fragment UI State like recyclerview scroll position, FAB button visibility, etc**

Comment: If you have used `replaceFragment` to navigate to fragment `B` then you can use `addFragment`. This will keep fragment `A` in back side and add fragment `B` above `A`. Now when you remove fragment `B` , fragment `A` will stay as it is.

Comment: I am using Navigation Component. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: you ca retrive fragment using support librart
`    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.my_container, myFragment, MY_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();
    } else {
        myFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(MY_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }`

Comment: The easiest way to keep UI states of Fragment is making it as Singleton object. So even if the life cycle is re-processed, UI states will be same as you left. Bcz same UI object will be returned in onCreateView.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store recyclerview scroll position, FAB button visibility in a variable and set those values after onViewCreated is called.

OR

You can store it in Bundle of onSaveInstanceState and retain its state

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```